# Babel installation issue: 'babel' package mistakenly installed, but 'babel-cli' is missing

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, babeljs, transpiler

I have a Java project with some JavaScript code I would like to transpile with Babel. I have performed the preliminary installation steps as indicated in the documentation on babeljs.io. My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "dataintegrationhub",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "babel .\\src\\main\\resources\\webroot\\js\\ --out-dir dist"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5"
  }
}
```

However, when I run npm install, a handful of empty folders appear under node_modules, and the .bin folder is missing. If I run, for example, the command npx babel .\src\main\resources\webroot\js\ --out-dir dist, I get the following error: "You have mistakenly installed the 'babel' package, which is a no-op in Babel 6. Babel's CLI commands have been moved from the 'babel' package to the 'babel-cli' package." It recommends running npm uninstall babel and npm install --save-dev babel-cli.

But even after following these steps, the issue persists. The strange thing is that the same configuration of package.json and babel.config.json works perfectly on another computer.

Can you help me understand?

On the machine where it is not working, I have:
node 18.15.0 npm 9.6.6.

While on the machine where it works, I have node 17.2.0 and npm 8.4.0.
Thank you in advance for your support and help.

Comment: Is the environment variable `NODE_ENV` possibly set to production when you npm install, stopping npm from installing devDependencies and then using some global or fetched `babel` via npx?